# Docker-compose down kills an app

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have a simple app which is an infinite loop:

```cs
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hey {0}", i++);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

I run this app with `docker-compose up -d`. It works fine:

```
myservice_1  | Hey 0
myservice_1  | Hey 1
myservice_1  | Hey 2
myservice_1  | Hey 3
myservice_1  | Hey 4
myservice_1  | Hey 5
myservice_1  | Hey 6
```

Okay, now I want to gracefully stop it:

```
docker-compose down -t 5
```

I suppose that because this is an infinite loop it will wait 5 seconds and then kill an app that didn't finish its work at time.

But in practice I get an application just killed immediatly after I press `enter`.

It scares me because it could be my product app that won't save something in database or perform some critical resource cleanup.

How can it be fixed?

---

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestApp.dll"]
```

---

Thanks to @muratiakos and @Miq, this code shutdowns gracefully:

```cs
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading += _ =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got SIGTERM");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        };

        for (int i = 0; ; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got {0}", i);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you run your app in the container?

Comment: @Yuankun i run it via `docker-compose`. If you are interested in `Dockerfile` content, please see edit.

Comment: Not familiar with dotnet, can you confirm that your app is handling the `SIGTERM` signal correctly?

Comment: @Yuankun in this case it's just an infinite loop that just ignore any signas or something. But maybe runtime just kills my app instead of docker... Thank you for idea, I should investiaget it.

Comment: Infinite loop does not respect signals - you need to first catch them and provide own method of handling. However you can handle only sigterm - sigkill will always terminate your app.

Comment: @Miq If my application gets SIGTERM and it doesn't react then app will be closed, but not before timeout expires. Is it incorrect?

Comment: If your app will receive sigterm, and you don't handle it, process will be terminated. Your application (in the form you presented) does not handle sigterm, therefore it will be terminated as the signal arrives. To test it, run your application without docker and press ctrl+c (this is sending sigterm to app).

Comment: @Miq I didn't suppose that SIGTERM should have some kind of affirmation from application in order to be not killed immediately. Thank you for this information, it was new for me.

Comment: https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/ and https://medium.com/@gchudnov/trapping-signals-in-docker-containers-7a57fdda7d86

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would implement your container to gracefully capture `signals`. Namely first to capture `SIGTERM` to start a graceful shutdown, so the container has time to even exit itself before it receives a kill signal with `SIGKILL`.

You can then call a graceful stop with

```
docker-compose kill -s SIGTERM
```

before you actually shut down the composition as per described under

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/kill/

In addition to docker compose the standard `stop --timeout 5` command also just issues a `SIGTERM` first and when the grace-period elapses it sends a `SIGKILL`.

Comment: I tried both `stop` and `kill` but my application still stops immediately before timeout is expired.

Comment: for the grace period to work you need to handle sigterm in the application. this period is to make the container stop no matter what after given timeout. A standard application will close after receiving sigterm. handling sigterm must be explicitly added.